# cmake: "add_custom_target" + PRE_BUILD didn't take effect while building

Tags: c++, cmake, dependencies, grpc, target

I've using cmake to build my google rpc sample code. I've got

```
 examples.proto
 client.cpp
 server.cpp
```

I use protoc command to build out .cc/.h files for both protobuf and grpc, CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
add_definitions(-std=c++11)
include_directories(.)

add_custom_target(protoFile
    PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND protoc --cpp_out=./ examples.proto
)
add_custom_target(protoSource
    PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND protoc --grpc_out=./ --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=/usr/local/bin/grpc_cpp_plugin examples.proto
)
add_dependencies(protoSource protoFile)

add_library(protoCpp SHARED examples.grpc.pb.cc examples.pb.cc)
add_dependencies(protoCpp protoSource)

link_libraries(protoCpp protobuf grpc grpc++)
add_executable(client client.cpp)
add_executable(server server.cpp)
```

And then:

```
cmake .
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:15 (add_library):
Cannot find source file:

    examples.grpc.pb.cc

Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
.hxx .in .txx


CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: protoCpp
CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "protoCpp".
-- Generating done
```

Seems my "add_custom_target()" was not executed, and "ls" didn't show any files I expected. So how to make them executed? I already added "protoSource as dependency for "protoCpp" library, but didn't work.

How to solve this?

Comment: Commands specified in `add_custom_target` or `add_custom_command` are executed at **build stage**, but you got an error at **configuration stage**. The error tells that CMake can neither find source **files** for `add_executable` nor find a command which generates them. You use `add_custom_command` and `add_custom_target` in a strange way. As you want to work with protobuf, why do not call [find_package(Protobuf)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/module/FindProtobuf.html) and use functions it provides?

Comment: Thanks, that works find for me. I also found this example file very good: https://github.com/jan-alexander/grpc-cpp-helloworld-cmake/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 0):

Use `add_custom_target` after `add_executable`, and the first parameter should be a target created by `add_executable`, in your example "client" or "server". You can't use `PRE_BUILD` in `add_custom_target`, but I'm not sure;

See also: [add_custom_target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html) documentation.